# android:how to create diagonal imageview like this picture?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

i need to create a layout like this:

[image]

and i created a simple layout like this,but it doesn't work for me and  i  need to a layout like uploaded image.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/frame1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:background="@drawable/frame1_selector"
                android:src="@drawable/earth"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.4"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and i searched internet but didn't find  xml based solution.

Comment: It's a normal PNG image with 2 transparent areas.

Comment: imageview will show different images from users,is your solution works for this case?

Comment: Yes. You can simply: **1** distort an image by skewing it. Or **2** apply a simple mask which cuts 2 transparent areas, using the adequate `PorterDuff XFerMode`. I prefer the 2nd solution (non distorting).

Comment: In case you were still wondering how to: http://www.piwai.info/transparent-jpegs-done-right/

Comment: i need to justify image in a billboard like this:http://www.echodgraphics.com/itemimageslarge/apple%20ipad%20mini%20billboard.jpg,

Comment: What does it mean? do you need to add margins?

Comment: first thank you for your answers,but i need to show different images in white area of this image(http://s5.picofile.com/file/8160841218/apple_ipad_mini_billboardbg.jpg) automatically,but i don't know have to use png with two transparent areas in this case?thank you again

Comment: Yes. The image is just the container background. More on porterDuff xFerMode: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html

Answer (score 0):

May be, it can be done by animating the `ImageView` to rotate 45° and setting `fillEnabled=true` and `fillAfter=true`, so that the `ImageView` stays in that position(45°) even after the animation has finished.

Also, set the animation's duration to “1" so that the animation can take place stealthily.